# how do i convert this array?

Tags: php

i have the following array:

```
["addToCart"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["aantal"]=>
      int(1)
      ["film_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["zaal_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["dag"]=>
      string(7) "maandag"
      ["seats"]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "67"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "68"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "69"
        [3]=>
        string(2) "70"
      }
    }
```

You can see that i have an array called "seats" inside the "addToCart" array.There are 4 items in the "seats" array.
what i would like to have is 4 separate arrays, they should all have the same content but each of them needs to have 1 value of "seats".

Comment: Can you give an example how the resulting array should look like?

Comment: You're missing the final closing curly brace FWIW....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I got exactly what you're looking to do, but this would result in an array of arrays where each has only one seat:

```
$seatArrays = array();

foreach ($addToCart as $arr)
{
  foreach ($arr["seats"] as $seat)
  {
    $seatArr = $arr;            // Copy the original array
    $seatArr["seats"] = $seat;  // Replace the "seats" subarray with the current seat
    $seatArrays[] = $seatArr;    
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what i am looking for but i asked the question wron, its actually a session array, and i need it to convert in the way you described but it should end up being a session array again. Maybe i sound dumb for not doing it by myself but i have no clue how to do it. I'm still learning from books etc and its harder than i thought.

Comment: I tried to adapt you code and mess around a bit with it but i found out that if you trace the following: 
foreach ($addToCart as $arr)
loses all the id's, it gives the following output.
'
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "maandag"
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
}
'

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're talking about... if the subarrays of `$addToCart` have keys, then `$arr` in `foreach ($addToCart as $arr)` will as well. And in terms of sessions, you can just put `$seatArray` back into your session...